# How do I open the SwipeMenuListView creator menu by line of code?

Tags: java, android

I'm Needing to Show My User, from my Application, in the tutorial, the options that give the Swipe List (SwipeMenuListView), for this the Item has to be open to be highlighted by TapTarget. I am begging your help to help me see a solution.

SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

```
        @Override
        public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
            // create "open" item
            SwipeMenuItem openItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            // set item background
            openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0x00, 0x66,
                    0xff)));
            // set item width
            openItem.setWidth(175);
            // set item title
            openItem.setIcon(R.drawable.iconedit);
            // set item background
            openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
            // add to menu
            menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

            // create "delete" item
            SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            // set item background
            deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                    0x3F, 0x25)));
            // set item width
            deleteItem.setWidth(175);
            // set a icon
            deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icondelete);
            // add to menu
            menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
        }
    };
    controle.setMenuCreator(creator);
```